# How to clean up redis hosted by cloudfoundry?

Tags: redis, cloud-foundry

The redis cache offered by [CloudFoundry](http://CloudFoundry.com) has a small capacity, i.e. 16MB.
I know redis has a command "[FLUSHALL](http://redis.io/commands/flushall)" which is used to delete all the keys in the cache. How to do the same thing in cloudfoundry?

Comment: Hm, connect to their redis and send FLUSHALL? Or is it forbidden there?

Comment: We cann't connect to their redis directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recreate and rebind the service as you wish unless you have any specific configuration that cannot be migrated. (I assume services provisioned by CF.com should be created as the same.)

Also sending FLUSHALL to the redis tunnel should be another option if you have vmc and caldecott gem installed as well as a redis execution locally. Would you mind if you can send the error why you cannot connect to it?

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide more doc on sending FLUSHALL to CF redis?

Comment: use the tunnelling capability e.g.

    vmc tunnel <your-redis-service>

Then run redis-cli and issue the FLUSHALL.